# Sockjs/socketio disconnect delay behind apache proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I need to handle users disconnecting from my sockjs application running in **xhr-polling** mode. When I connect to server directly, everything works as expected. When I put apache between nodejs and browser, I get ~20 sec delay between closed browser and disconnect event inside nodejs. My apache proxy config is following:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Location>
```

The rest of the file is default, you can see it here. I tried playing with ttl=2 and timeout=2 options, but either nothing changes, or I get reconnected each 2 seconds without closing browser. Also tried disablereuse=On, and it doesn't help.

How can I reduce additional disconnect timeout, introduced, but apache, somewhere in its defaults?

Comment: Do you see a difference when setting `ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/ retry=0 timeout=10`? If the cause is the reverse proxy, try to bypass name resolution by using the hosts file for resolution.

Comment: It would be nice if the poster or the bounty-giver would answer this comment.

Comment: Another abandoned post.

Comment: I have no working app to test this now, sorry. May be later.

Comment: @harrymc I was not alerted that you had commented on this question and only just saw it because of the notice that my bounty was expiring. I have also posted my own question with a bounty as well and would prefer to work with my own code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461117/catching-disconnects-with-apache-load-balancer-and-node-io-socket-backend

Comment: My issue only seems to happen when I have a (virtual) subdirectory in the URL so I think mine is probably a different issue.